# "Only User1 can do that" restriction with triggers

Tags: oracle, triggers

I want to implement a condition on trigger which basically say: 'Only user: Boss can do that'

I searched everywhere and I didn't find anything...

In my trigger, only the boss can increase the salary by 20%

This is what I've already done:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BOSSPERMISSION
       BEFORE UPDATE
       ON teachers
       FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
    error EXCEPTION;

BEGIN

    IF (((:NEW.SALARY-:OLD.SALARY)/:OLD.SALARY)*100) > 20 THEN
       -- Here i want to include another if condition which says what I asked
          
       END IF;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN error THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002,'You're not the boss');
    
END;
/
```

I work on Oracle SQL.

---

#### Solved

Response below, make sure you delete the old triggers.

Comment: You probably doing wrong. You handle those logic on the bussiness layer.

Answer (score 2):

In the trigger body:

```
if USER<>'BOSS' then
  RAISE;
end if;
```

UPDATE:

```
create or replace trigger BOSSPERMISSION before update on teachers
for each row
begin
  if user<>'BOSS' then
    raise_application_error(-20001,'Only Bawse can do it');
  end if;
end;
```

OUTPUT (worked for me):

```
Trigger created.
update teachers set salary = salary*1.3
Error at line xx
ORA-20001: Only Bawse can do it
ORA-06512: at "BOSSPERMISSION", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'BOSSPERMISSION'
```

Comment: So this is what i've done with you help, i've just put this in the first if condition.

IF (USER != 'GrandChef') THEN
     RAISE error;
      END IF;

The trigger has been created but it doesn't work. In fact, i created a user named 'Boss' and when i try to increase more than 20% the salary of a teacher it raise me the exception from the trigger (named error)

Comment: @ChrisBlp - does your string literal have the same case as the username in the `dba_users` table? Unless you've used a quoted identifier, you need to compare with `'BOSS'`, not `'Boss'`.

Comment: @ChrisBlp: String comparison in Oracle is case sensitive: `'BOSS'` is a different value the `'Boss'`

Comment: I tried this : 
update teacher set salary = 40000000 where num_teach =1;
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20002: You’re not the boss
ORA-06512: at "BOSS.BOSSPERMISSION", line 14
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'BOSS.BOSSPERMISSION'

The strings have the same case.

Comment: what's the output of your session's "select user from dual;" --?

Comment: The output is BOSS

Comment: @access_granted could you try to do it with a user BOSS ?

Comment: Works with BOSS, doesn't work with other UIDs. Can you post your final trigger?